# Windows Process-Based Audio Output Recorder and Mixer

Tags: windows-8, audio-recording

This utility probably doesn't exist.  If it did, I would probably already know about it.  That said, is anybody aware of a utility that can record and mix audio on a per-process (or audio stream) level?

For example, let's say I'm playing Portal 2, and I want to capture the audio from the game, the audio from my partner, and the audio from my mic, all independently, such that I can combine them at a later date without fear of messing up the levels.

The audio comes from: skype.exe, an input device, and portal2.exe.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Virtual Audio Cables](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) several years ago. I remember it did work as advertised (I used it to send Skype audio over the network as SIP, and it kinda worked, but there were issues: latency and sync., if I remember correctly. This was many versions ago, though).

> Virtual Audio Cable software allows you to transfer audio (wave) streams between applications and/or devices.
>
> It creates a set of virtual audio devices named "Virtual Cables", each of them consists of a pair of the waveform input/output devices. Any application can send audio stream to an output side of a cable, and any other application can receive this stream from an input side. All transfers are made digitally, providing NO sound quality loss (a bitperfect streaming).

Comment: Ha I knew this sounded familiar but couldn't think why until I read your answer: You can download the WinDDK and compile your own virtual audio driver. I don't know whether you can use it by itself to then redirect audio - I just used it to provide fake audio drivers for VMs where our software tests would fail if Windows didn't think a sound device was present. It was a little bit of a hassle because you have to self-sign the drivers and then set the guest OS to allow self-signed drivers, but it worked.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to revoke my previous comment.  This does not, in fact, solve my problem.  It mandates that you be able to select the output audio device in the application itself, and acts as a physical audio cable between ports on your motherboard/sound card.  Not any more useful than the Windows' solution.